# Split numbers based on dataframe column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I am a novice python programmer and I have a task at hand which needs a little logic designing. So I have a data frame with the below mentioned values in User, Task and Hours invested by the user for that task:

| User | Task | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | T1 | 8 |
| John | T2 | 32 |
| Alex | A1 | 40 |
| Bob | B1 | 16 |

Now what I need to do is, generate a new dataframe on a weekly basis which contains the user, task code and the hours divided into 5 (5 working days in a week of 7 days). Note that max hours per week cannot exceed 40 i.e 8 hours per day.

**For Alex**:
The division is simple. 8 hours per day for 5 days will give me 40 hours of worktime.

| User | Task | hours | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | A1 | 8 | 1 |
| Alex | A1 | 8 | 2 |
| Alex | A1 | 8 | 3 |
| Alex | A1 | 8 | 4 |
| Alex | A1 | 8 | 5 |

Now it gets tricky.

**For Bob**:
The division will be 16/5 = 3.2. But I need to enter whole numbers (4) and adjust the leftover on the last day.

| User | Task | hours | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | B1 | 3 | 1 |
| Bob | B1 | 3 | 2 |
| Bob | B1 | 3 | 3 |
| Bob | B1 | 3 | 4 |
| Bob | B1 | 4 | 5 |

**For John**:

This is the most tricky one. I need to split the 2 task's hours (32 and 8) among 5 days.

I need 8 split up into 2-2-2-2 for 4 days or 4-4 for 2 days

and   32 split up into 6-6-6-6-8 for 5 days or 4-4-8-8-8 for 5 days

Considering the 1st cases for both, we would get something like this:

| User | Task | hours | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | T1 | 2 | 1 |
| John | T2 | 6 | 1 |
| John | T1 | 2 | 2 |
| John | T2 | 6 | 2 |
| John | T1 | 2 | 3 |
| John | T2 | 6 | 3 |
| John | T1 | 2 | 4 |
| John | T2 | 6 | 4 |
| John | T2 | 8 | 5 |

I am sorry if my format or language is inappropriate or not adhering the guidelines. My apologies.

I would be extremely grateful of you could help me figure out a logic for this. A big thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want a separate dataframe for each user?

Comment: And do you want to round up or down, if the number is not whole?

Comment: You will need a rule for how you want to split the hours. If you have that, then the process can be simplified. If you dont have a specific rule, having guidelines of some sort can be helpful

Comment: Hi, So uptill now no guidelines. I just need to make sure that the hours are divided and fulfilled (40 hours per week). I can generate different dataframes for each and the concatenate in one master dataframe. Rounding might not affect as closest whole number is used.  @LoukasPap,

Comment: @AbilashReznovSubbaraman Hi, So uptill now no guidelines. I just need to make sure that the hours are divided and fulfilled (40 hours per week). I can generate different dataframes for each and the concatenate in one master dataframe. Rounding might not affect as closest whole number is used.

Comment: For John on T1, could it be `Day 1-4: 1 hour` and `Day 5: 4 hours`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `import numpy as np`

Our dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["John", "T1",8],
    ["John", "T2", 32],
    ["Alex","A1",40],
    ["Bob","B1",16]],
    columns=["User", "Task", 'Hours'])
```

```py
# We create a column with the average work hours
df["avg"] = df["Hours"] / 5

# A column with the leftover hours of the first 4 days of week
df["leftover"] = (df["avg"] - np.floor(df2["avg"]) ) * 4

# We create a function, in which we will store in a list
# the working hours for each day, adding the leftovers in the 5th day.
# The elements of the list are tuples following the format (<working-hours>, <nth-day>)
def days_list(row):
    days = [(np.floor(row["avg"]), i+1) for i in range(4)]
    days.append((np.floor(row["leftover"] + row["avg"]), 5))
    return days

df["list_of_days"] = df.apply(lambda row: days_list(row), axis=1) # applying the function

# We explode the column 'list_of_days' so as to have a row for each tuple
df = df.explode("list_of_days")

# Finally, we unzip the values of each tuple in the 2 columns 'Hours' & 'Days' accordingly.
df['Hours'], df['Days'] = zip(*df["list_of_days"])
```

Keeping the columns we need and printing the Dataframe :

```py
final_df = df[["User", "Task", "Hours", "Days"]]
final_df
```

| User | Task | Hours | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | T1 | 1.0 | 1 |
| John | T1 | 1.0 | 2 |
| John | T1 | 1.0 | 3 |
| John | T1 | 1.0 | 4 |
| John | T1 | 4.0 | 5 |
| John | T2 | 6.0 | 1 |
| John | T2 | 6.0 | 2 |
| John | T2 | 6.0 | 3 |
| John | T2 | 6.0 | 4 |
| John | T2 | 8.0 | 5 |
| Alex | A1 | 8.0 | 1 |
| Alex | A1 | 8.0 | 2 |
| Alex | A1 | 8.0 | 3 |
| Alex | A1 | 8.0 | 4 |
| Alex | A1 | 8.0 | 5 |
| Bob | B1 | 3.0 | 1 |
| Bob | B1 | 3.0 | 2 |
| Bob | B1 | 3.0 | 3 |
| Bob | B1 | 3.0 | 4 |
| Bob | B1 | 4.0 | 5 |

Comment: This solution worked like a charm. Your logic fits perfectly well. A huge Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: I am very glad I helped!@FarzadAvari